# Android Contact Picker With Checkbox

Tags: android, android-contacts

There are a lot of discussions going on about the same subject, but after spending 4 hours here, I could not find a valid description or a link to make a Contact Picker with Checkbox.

I have an activity with **DONE** button and `listview` with `checkbox`. I have managed to show the contacts correctly. Now I want to return the selected contact phone numbers in a `bundle` (I think the best way) so that I can get the list of numbers in `onActivityResult()`. I am not sure of the way I am following is right or not.

Here is my code:

```
public class ContactPickerMulti extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

    // List variables
    public String[] Contacts = {};
    public int[] to = {};
    public ListView myListView;

    Button save_button;
    private TextView phone;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_multi);

        // Initializing the buttons according to their ID
        save_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact_done);

        // Defines listeners for the buttons
        save_button.setOnClickListener(this);

        Cursor mCursor = getContacts();
        startManagingCursor(mCursor);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                mCursor,
                Contacts = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
                to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        myListView = getListView();
        myListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    }

    private Cursor getContacts() {
        // Run query
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '"
                + ("1") + "'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                sortOrder);
    }

    public void onClick(View src) {
        Intent i;
        switch (src.getId()) {
        case R.id.contact_done:

            SparseBooleanArray selectedPositions = myListView
                    .getCheckedItemPositions();
            SparseBooleanArray checkedPositions = myListView
                    .getCheckedItemPositions();
            if (checkedPositions != null) {
                for (int k = 0; k < checkedPositions.size(); k++) {
                     if (checkedPositions.valueAt(k)) {
                          String name =
                                 ((Cursor)myListView.getAdapter().getItem(k)).getString(1);
                            Log.i("XXXX",name + " was selected");
                        }
                }
            }

            break;
        }

    }
}
```

I want to send the numbers as array or list. What is the best way to do this? Any help or leading to right path is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add adapter code so i can know how you get phoneNumber.

Comment: @Yul code updated..Now it will print the name of the contact :)
I just need to get the phone number instead of Name ;)
Finished!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this code in `onClick`:

```
long[] id = getListView().getCheckedItemIds();//  i get the checked contact_id instead of position
        phoneNumber = new String[id.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {

            phoneNumber[i] = getPhoneNumber(id[i]); // get phonenumber from selected id

        }

        Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent();
        pickContactIntent.putExtra("PICK_CONTACT", phoneNumber);// Add checked phonenumber in intent and finish current activity.
        setResult(RESULT_OK, pickContactIntent);
        finish();
```

//

```
private String getPhoneNumber(long id) {
    String phone = null;
    Cursor phonesCursor = null;
    phonesCursor = queryPhoneNumbers(id);
    if (phonesCursor == null || phonesCursor.getCount() == 0) {
        // No valid number
        signalError();
        return null;
    } else if (phonesCursor.getCount() == 1) {
        // only one number, call it.
        phone = phonesCursor.getString(phonesCursor
                .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
    } else {
        phonesCursor.moveToPosition(-1);
        while (phonesCursor.moveToNext()) {

            // Found super primary, call it.
            phone = phonesCursor.getString(phonesCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
            break;

        }
    }

    return phone;
}


private Cursor queryPhoneNumbers(long contactId) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Uri baseUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            contactId);
    Uri dataUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

    Cursor c = cr.query(dataUri, new String[] { Phone._ID, Phone.NUMBER,
            Phone.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, Phone.TYPE,
            Phone.LABEL }, Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
            new String[] { Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE }, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        return c;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And the last `onActivityResult` of activity which you start `PickContactsActivity`

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT) {


            if (data != null) {

                String[] temp = data.getStringArrayExtra("PICK_CONTACT");

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thanks a lot. BTW I am having errors, `phonesCursor = queryPhoneNumbers(id);` what should I need to do in `queryPhoneNumbers(id);`

Comment: That is the id of checked contact you got in`onClick` `getPhoneNumber(id[i]);` . I'm using this code for my app so i assure it run. So you just have to change a little bit to fit yours

Comment: I am totaly lost somewhere, here is my current code http://pastebin.com/tdTpFR6t
can you please have a look at it?

Comment: can you please post the `queryPhoneNumbers(id);` method ?

Comment: Edit my post. Sorry wrong copy so it double `getPhoneNumber` method

Comment: Try to `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`O` to import. And come to this [room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people) i will help you out

Comment: this is close to what im doing, but i edited some parts so to retrieve not only the numbers but somewhat the whole record

Answer (score 2):

When using `startActivityForResult(newActivity)` in the `newActivity` you must make a call to `setResult(RESULT_OK)` followed by `finish()` to close the `Activity`. Optionally you can include an `Intent` in the call to `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)`. The call to `setResult()` will lead to calling your implementation of `onActivityResult()` where you can handle the result of the `Activity`. So in your case you would just create an `Intenet` and add your array list to it using one of the `putExtra()` methods. That `Intent` will then be passed to `onActivityResult()` where you can extract that information. See [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have updated the code and now I can get the checked item position. So how can I get the contact info? I mean I only have the item position and how can I query to make the LIST? Any idea?

Comment: You can get any sort of data, so where is the problem ? Just put an ArrayList or something.