# ListView with custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a class for the row, it extends `RelativeLayout` and inflates some layout to self. A `CheckBox` checked state listener is also set.

```
public class LayersListRow extends RelativeLayout {         

  public LayersListRow (Context context, final GITuple tuple) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layers_list_item, this, true);
        ...

    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.layers_list_item_switch);

    checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        ...
        }
    });
  }
    ...
}
```

I have a custom `ArrayAdapter`, which is filled with some objects of this class. I want to use them as the view too.

```
public class LayersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LayersListRow> {

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getItem(position);
    }

    public LayersAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
    }
}
```

But when I set this adapter to my `ListView` the `CheckBox`'s listener doesn't work. But for the items which appears on scroll down, it works fine.

If I replace `return getItem(position);` in the `getView` method with

```
if (null == convertView)
  return getItem(position);

return convertedView;
```

then for all items visible at first in the list listener works great, but when I try to scroll I get wrong item (the first one again), `ListView` freezes and don't respond.

Why is this happening and how should I make it work properly?

Comment: Do you mind posting the whole code of the adapter?

Comment: @Luksprog it is the whole code of my `LayersAdapter` class :)

Comment: I was interested in the `getItem(position)` method.

Comment: @Luksprog it's `Adapter` [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem(int)), I'm not overriding it.

Comment: Aha, but that means you're passing a list/array of your custom views to your adapter, which you shouldn't do. You should create the views in the `getView` method and pass a list of `GITuple`(which I assume is your row data) to the adapter and bind it to the row view in the same `getView` method.

Comment: @Luksprog yeah, I think you're right, but I wonder, why can't I just have these views stored and use them when I need? Is there some hidden internal work with my stored views or displayed views?

Comment: *why can't I just have these views stored and use them when I need?* - You can but you'll go against the entire purpose of a `ListView`, to not have to create all the views that the layout requires initially(which could even make your app crash if you have to many views/rows). Also in your custom view's constructor try something like this: `View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layers_list_item, this, false); CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.layers_list_item_switch);addView(v);`

Comment: @Luksprog thanks, I made it like you said and it works now. Still, I don't understand why storing views doesn't work good, but whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use this

```
if (null == convertView)
  return getItem(position);

return convertedView;
```

The view are reused. Hence when you scroll the views that where first shown will again be shown.

I would recommend you to see the answer I have written in this post. If you cannot follow it put a comment down here.

[Get checked Listitems from ListView and pass that to another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427262/get-checked-listitems-from-listview-and-pass-that-to-another-activity/12427720#12427720)