# Multiple select number from contact list

Tags: android, android-contacts

I wanna make enable to choose multiple contact number from contact list

I use this code for call caontact list

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
```

and on action result

```
    if (data != null) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    if (uri != null) {
                        Cursor c = null;
                        try {
                            c = getContentResolver()
                                    .query(uri,
                                            new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER },
                                            null, null, null);

                            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                                String tmp = c.getString(0);
}
```

but I just can select one number !

**how can I make list of contact multiple selection ?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Contact Picker With Checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413159/android-contact-picker-with-checkbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such like multiple contact picker in Android SDK, instead we usually make a [custom implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413159/android-contact-picker-with-checkbox/) (i.e. by making activity with listView). As said in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21305471/3913590), there's no such 'official' way to do this.