# How to access android contacts into an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, import, android-contacts

I'm just begining on Android and Java in general and Im trying to write an app that allows you to select your some of your contacts, grabbing their Name and main number and putting them into seperate list arrays. I'm not sure how to go about doing that so I've only added it in manually where you must type each persons name and number.

```
List<String> phnnumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbersview);
// Defines the box where we will grab the numbers
EditText addnumberfieldbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addnumberfield);
EditText nameboxtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.namebox);
// Grabs the box's contents and puts it into useable data
Editable numberfieldEditable = addnumberfieldbox.getText();
Editable nameboxEditable = nameboxtext.getText();
// Finally uses the data from the box, and puts it in
String numberfieldString = numberfieldEditable.toString();
String nameboxString = nameboxEditable.toString();
names.add(nameboxString);
phnnumbers.add(numberfieldString);
```

That's the method I'm using to get the text and put it into arrays.

Comment: Follow this tutorial => https://github.com/ChiragSavsani/ContactManager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the contact list of your phone you need to follow these steps :

**Step 1 :** Add permission to access contacts in your manifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

**Step 2 :** Use the following code to fetch name and phone number and then store them to ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

public void addContacts(){

    //to store name-number pair
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    try {
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            obj.put(name, phoneNumber);
            contacts.add(obj);

            Log.e("Contact list with name & numbers", " "+contacts);
        }
        phones.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can use the **ArrayList contacts** in your application code.

Comment: Okay  that explained to me how to actually grab contacts themselves, but Im wondering how I would allow the user to select some of the contacts from their contact list,  and using only the contacts they selected, add those into my arrays(phnnumbers and names respectively).  Would I have to grab all the contacts into a different array, do a popup of some sort, allow the user to select some, then move those to the phnnumbers and names array? or is there a built in way using the contacts app?

Comment: Well, there is no official way to select contacts from phonebook. So, you have to follow the approach you have already mentioned in the above comment. For guidance, you can follow this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12425005/4116262)

Answer (score 0):

1 - Put the permissions on your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > ...
```

2 - import ContactsContract

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
```

3 - Populate a cursor with phone contacts:

```
  ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
  Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
   null, null, null, null);
```

4 - Populate ArrayLists

```
  List<String> phnnumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
  List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

  if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
   while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = cur.getString(
cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String phoneNumber =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            names.add(name);
            phnnumbers.add(phoneNumber);

        }
  }
```

Comment: thank you, I've learned what cursors are now and how useful they are. However, how would I only grab contacts a user selected? see my comment above for more info